# Is there a web application that can notify you ahead of time if a certain weather forecast is predicted for a certain location?

Tags: weather, preparation

In other words, it would be a site where you can "subscribe" to certain locations and then have the service email you if the weather forecast matches the kind of weather conditions you are looking for.

I believe a site like this would serve as a valuable tool for many types of outdoor activities and trips.

Sure, there is value in just being out there even if the weather is not ideal. Indeed, often we are forced to make do with the conditions we are given. With that said, however, wouldn't it be great if you could expect with reasonable certainty your ideal weather conditions, and have it be sent to your inbox?

Examples might include:

- Get an email the next time a weekend following 3 days of snow is predicted at ski resort
- Get an email the next time there is a full moon and clear sky for a summer night hike
- (I'm sure there are many other examples: water sports, fishing, running, etc)

So does anyone know of anything like this?

Comment: We have a bunch of meteorologists at work, so I asked them for you. None of them could think of a tool like you wanted. Sorry. Though some of the programmers at work thought it might make a fun project; it's a good idea.

Answer (score 8):

You can use **[IFTTT (If This, Then That)](https://ifttt.com/)**.  You can use it to create your own rules to check the weather for you and then email or even text you with a link and what kind of condition changes.

For example, mine is set to email me whenever there is more than X change in temperature, or if it is going to specifically rain/snow or have something out of the blue like thunderstorm, etc... then it emails me 1-2 days in advance... Usually it emails me for the next two days...

Pretty neat app and useful for all kinds of other things, free as well. I'm not affiliated either.

Answer (score 5):

There's no such site that I know of, but there's a couple of alternatives that may suit your needs:

- Google calendar has an add on you can enable which shows the [weather as an icon](http://support.google.com/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=48494) by the next few days. I find this quite useful (obviously it depends if you use Google calendar!)
- There's a few websites which will do a general email newsletter. While you want something more specific, you could set up a filter in your email client for certain keywords from that address, so you only actually saw the message if it contained the description of the weather you were looking for.

Like I said, not exactly matching up to what you're after but that might go at least some way towards it!

Answer (score 5):

This isn't pretty, and seems to be somewhat limited in locations (I couldn't get it to work for my area) but this looks to have potential. Though there is no "subscribe" feature.

[National Weather Service Weather Activity Planner (Example)](http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?b0=t&b0mn=50&b0mx=85&b1=rh&b1mn=&b1mx=&b2=wskts&b2mn=8&b2mx=15&b3=wsmph&b3mn=&b3mx=&b4=sc&b4mn=0&b4mx=60&b5=pp&b5mn=0&b5mx=15&lat=37.5269&lon=-122.193&Submit=Submit&FcstType=wxplan&site=MTR&unit=0)